# Java: accessing a List of Strings as an InputStream

Tags: java, java-io

Is there any way `InputStream` wrapping a list of UTF-8 `String`? I'd like to do something like:

```
InputStream in = new XyzInputStream( List<String> lines )
```

Comment: Can you share the situation, why you want this?

Comment: Note that `InputStream` deals with *binary* data. Strings are *text* data. Which encoding are you interested in?

Comment: You're right I forgot to precise : UTF-8 only.

Comment: How did you finally accomplish creating an InputStream from List<String> Marc? I have to do the same thing. Any Input will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can concatenate all the lines together to create a String then convert it to a byte array using `String#getBytes` and pass it into [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). However this is not the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: You can implement a InputStream yourself and convert each String to a byte array as you go along and wrap it in a ByteArrayInputStream and forward the calls to the ByteArrayInputStream. Though, seeing as you will have to have logic dealing with splitting reads across Strings it's probably just as easy to do all the logic yourself and not use ByteArrayInputStream at all.

Comment: @Marc avoiding this copy is not necessary a good idea. It allows you to process all the data at once. If the strings are small this can save you a lot of object allocations. It can be faster and in some cases even consume less memory. Whatever you do, benchmark it on sample data and make sure it really is more efficient.

Comment: @Marc You *can* avoid the copy, but not without writing a significant amount of code. You would have to implement InputStream yourself, and somehow adapt all of its methods to working over a List of Strings, which will be an enormous pain to do, and won't buy you that much in terms of performance or reduced memory footprint.

Answer (score 18):

You can read from a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and you can create your source `byte[]` array using a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

So create the array as follows:

```
 List<String> source = new ArrayList<String>();
 source.add("one");
 source.add("two");
 source.add("three");
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 for (String line : source) {
   baos.write(line.getBytes());
 }

 byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

And reading from it is as simple as:

```
 InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Alternatively, depending on what you're trying to do, a [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) might be better.

Comment: This is the best way of doing it if it's a one-off. If you have to reuse instances of the InputStream all over the place though, you could always implement the InputStream interface, and do all of the above under the hood.

Comment: Good example, but it would be nice to encourage best practice by specifying a charset during `getBytes()`.

Answer (score 5):

In short, no, there is no way of doing this using existing JDK classes. You could, however, implement your own [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) that read from a List of Strings.

EDIT: Dave Web has an answer above, which I think is the way to go. If you need a reusable class, then something like this might do:

```
public class StringsInputStream<T extends Iterable<String>> extends InputStream {

   private ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;

   public StringsInputStream(final T strings) throws IOException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      for (String line : strings) {
         outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
      }
      bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
   }

   @Override
   public int read() throws IOException {
      return bais.read();
   }

   @Override
   public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
      return bais.read(b);
   }

   @Override
   public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
      return bais.read(b, off, len);
   }

   @Override
   public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
      return bais.skip(n);
   }

   @Override
   public int available() throws IOException {
      return bais.available();
   }

   @Override
   public void close() throws IOException {
      bais.close();
   }

   @Override
   public synchronized void mark(int readlimit) {
      bais.mark(readlimit);
   }

   @Override
   public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
      bais.reset();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean markSupported() {
      return bais.markSupported();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      List source = new ArrayList();
      source.add("foo ");
      source.add("bar ");
      source.add("baz");

      StringsInputStream<List<String>> in = new StringsInputStream<List<String>>(source);

      int read = in.read();
      while (read != -1) {
         System.out.print((char) read);
         read = in.read();
      }
   }
}
```

This basically an adapter for `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create some kind of IterableInputStream

```
public class IterableInputStream<T> extends InputStream {

    public static final int EOF = -1;

    private static final InputStream EOF_IS = new InputStream() {
        @Override public int read() throws IOException {
            return EOF;
        }
    };

    private final Iterator<T> iterator;
    private final Function<T, byte[]> mapper;

    private InputStream current;

    public IterableInputStream(Iterable<T> iterable, Function<T, byte[]> mapper) {
        this.iterator = iterable.iterator();
        this.mapper = mapper;
        next();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int n = current.read();
        while (n == EOF && current != EOF_IS) {
            next();
            n = current.read();
        }
        return n;
    }

    private void next() {
        current = iterator.hasNext() 
            ? new ByteArrayInputStream(mapper.apply(iterator.next())) 
            : EOF_IS;
    }
}
```

To use it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Iterable<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "22", "333", "4444");
    try (InputStream is = new IterableInputStream<String>(strings, String::getBytes)) {
        for (int b = is.read(); b != -1; b = is.read()) {
            System.out.print((char) b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually a great idea. In my case I can't operate on whole list or else I'd get OutOfMemory.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to convert a list of string in the equivalent file (with a line feed for each line).

This was my solution:

```
List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList("line1", "line2", "line3");

byte[] bytes = inputList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n", "", "\n")).getBytes();

InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Awesome solution! Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. But because the Collectors.joining does *not* add a final line feed I switched to a enhanced-loop solution (so last line in file also ends with a line feed).

Comment: @StephanvanHoof for the final line feed just try `Collectors.joining("\n", "", "\n")`. BTW I've just updated my answer :)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know of this method overload

Comment: I copied this solution, but as I needed a EOF character for different platforms (Windows and Linux), I used `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: @FelipeWindmoller thanks for the suggestion,I’ll update My answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to this:

https://commons.apache.org/sandbox/flatfile/xref/org/apache/commons/flatfile/util/ConcatenatedInputStream.html

It just implements the read() method of InputStream and has a list of InputStreams it is concatenating. Once it reads an EOF it starts reading from the next InputStream. Just convert the Strings to ByteArrayInputStreams.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this way create a Serializable List

```
List<String> quarks = Arrays.asList(
      "up", "down", "strange", "charm", "top", "bottom"
    );

//serialize the List
//note the use of abstract base class references

try{
  //use buffering
  OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream( "quarks.ser" );
  OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream( file );
  ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream( buffer );
  try{
    output.writeObject(quarks);
  }
  finally{
    output.close();
  }
}  
catch(IOException ex){
  fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform output.", ex);
}

//deserialize the quarks.ser file
//note the use of abstract base class references

try{
  //use buffering
  InputStream file = new FileInputStream( "quarks.ser" );
  InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream( file );
  ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream ( buffer );
  try{
    //deserialize the List
    List<String> recoveredQuarks = (List<String>)input.readObject();
    //display its data
    for(String quark: recoveredQuarks){
      System.out.println("Recovered Quark: " + quark);
    }
  }
  finally{
    input.close();
  }
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
  fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input. Class not found.", ex);
}
catch(IOException ex){
  fLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot perform input.", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose my simple solution:

```java
public class StringListInputStream extends InputStream {
    private final List<String> strings;
    private int pos = 0;
    private byte[] bytes = null;
    private int i = 0;

    public StringListInputStream(List<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
        this.bytes = strings.get(0).getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (pos >= bytes.length) {
            if (!next()) return -1;
            else return read();
        }
        return bytes[pos++];
    }

    private boolean next() {
        if (i + 1 >= strings.size()) return false;
        pos = 0;
        bytes = strings.get(++i).getBytes();
        return true;
    }
}
```